# Intent to open default camera in square mode

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I can open a camera from intent by this:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = Utility.createImageFile(BotActivity.this);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File

                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(BotActivity.this,
                                "com.kutumbita.app.fileprovider",
                                photoFile);

                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_REQUEST);
                    }
                }
```

Is there any way in the intent to start that camera with square size on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have came to the solution that, this is not possible with native android sdk. Thanks